# MySQL returns infinite number of values

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to build a autocomplete input for suggesting users to page.

I have a table called '**users**' with fields

> 'id', 'fullname','username', 'picture',

a table '**project_admin**' with fields

> 'id','project_id', 'user_id4

and a table '**project_member**' with fields :

> 'id','project_id', 'user_id'.

I want to get all the users that are neither admins nor members for a particular project_id and have a $term in their fullname or username

I use the following query:

```
SELECT users.fullname,users.id,users.picture
FROM users, project_member, project_admin
WHERE (users.fullname LIKE '$term%'
OR users.username LIKE '$term%')
AND users.id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM project_member WHERE project_id=$project_id)
AND users.id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM project_admin WHERE project_id=$project_id) 
LIMIT 0,10
```

Unfortunately the result I get is infinite number of dublicates of the first result. What should I do?

SOLVED
Yes, thanks to all of you. Really users.id,users.picture is the problem, when removed, everything goes smoothly

Comment: "infinite"?  Hardly.....

Comment: `DISTINCT` is the worst advice here.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few issues with your original query that is causing the large result set that it is returning.

First, you are not actually joining the `users`, `project_member` and `project_admin` tables on any particular column.  As a result you are creating a Cartesian product between them.  So if `users` has 500 and `project_member` has 7800 and `project_admin` has 6545 rows, then you are starting with 25,525,500,000 rows. I don't think this is the intention with your query.

Second, you are not using the `project_member` and `project_admin` in the final result, so you don't actually need to join on them. You should be able to use:

```
select u.fullname, u.id, u.picture
from users u
where (u.fullname LIKE '$term%' or u.username LIKE '$term%')
and u.id NOT IN (SELECT user_id 
                 FROM project_member 
                 WHERE project_id=$project_id)
and u.id NOT IN (SELECT user_id 
                 FROM project_admin 
                 WHERE project_id=$project_id)
LIMIT 0,10
```

If you want to return data from the `project_member` and `project_admin` tables, then consider joining the tables with a `LEFT JOIN` instead of the `CROSS JOIN` that you are currently using.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue, I think, is because you unnecessarly join on the three tables, where you dont need too. You only need
to fetch the data from the users table and exclude any matches on username found in the others based on the project id.

Here is what I would use:

```
SELECT 
  users.id, users.fullname, users.picture
FROM 
  users
WHERE 
  (users.fullname LIKE '$term%' OR users.username LIKE '$term%') 
AND 
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM project_member AS a WHERE a.project_id = '$project_id' AND a.user_id = users.id
  )
AND
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM project_admin AS b WHERE b.project_id = '$project_id'  AND b.user_id = users.id
  )
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also phrase this as a `left outer join`, rather than using `not in`:

```
SELECT users.fullname,users.id,users.picture
FROM users left outer join
     project_member
     on project_member.user_id = users.id left outer join
     project_admin
     on project_admin.user_id = users.id
WHERE (users.fullname LIKE '$term%' OR users.username LIKE '$term%') and
      project_member.user_id is NULL and
      project_admin.user_id is NULL
LIMIT 0,10
```

You should simply not use `,` in the `from` clause.  If you want a Cartesian product, then explicitly use `cross join`.

Comment: If someone has an idea why this was downvoted, I'd like to know why.